# NodeJS Express Session writeFile

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I'm experiencing a very unusual problem that I can't seem to find much help on. In my Express app I am using my own file-based session store handler, but am having trouble with the set function.

Originally, I wrote to disk the async way:

```
store.prototype.set = function( session_id, session, cb ) {

    ...

    // save content to disk
    g.modules.fs.writeFile( file, content, function( error ) {
        if ( error ) {
            return cb && cb( error );
        }

        cb && cb();
    });
};
```

However, I noticed a problem.  If at any time in the call stack of the request being processed there was an unhandled exception, `writeFile` would not complete and the session file on disk became corrupted.

So I then switched to the sync way:

```
store.prototype.set = function( session_id, session, cb ) {

    ...

    // save content to disk
    g.modules.fs.writeFileSync( file, content );

    cb && cb();
};
```

However, this is causing a new problem. There seems to be a problem with the server sending content back to the client because Chrome says `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`.

[image: Error]

So my first question is which write method is typically used in Node apps for session storage, async or sync? If it's the former, how can I avoid the file corruption on unhandled exceptions that exit the process? If it's the latter, why is there an issue with Express sending content back to the client?